# Laravel 5.1 PHPUnit - press() gives me 'Unreachable field ""'

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-5.1

When trying to call the `press()` method, I always get

> InvalidArgumentException: Unreachable field ""

at that line.

According to the docs:

> "Press" a button with the given text or name.

My method:

```
press('Create')
```

and my button is

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Create</button>
```

I have also tried to use the `name` with the same result.

I have also tried `submitForm('Create')` which works, but then `seeInDatabase('employees', ['email' => 'john@email.com'])` always fails.

> Unable to find row in database table [employees] that matched attributes [{"email":"john@email.com"}].

Here is my full method

```
public function testExample()
{

  $this->actingAs(\App\Employee::where('username', 'grant')->first())
    ->visit('/employees/create')
    ->type('john', 'username')
    ->type('1234', 'password')
    ->type('john@email.com', 'email')
    ->submitForm('Create')
    ->seeInDatabase('employees', ['email' => 'john@email.com'])
    ->see('Employee Directory');
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

Here is my form:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'employees.store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
  @include('employees.form')
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

As you can see, there's no way my fields are outside of the form.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. It might be related to a failed client-side validation.

Comment: I don't think it's to do with the button, but the other fields that are being submitted in the form. The "" suggests that it might be related to an input with an array name (e.g. name="email[]"). Can you post a sample of your form?

Comment: If your input has an array name as stated by WebSpanner, you can give your input an id which is the same as the name but without the array declaration and reference the input in PHPUnit without the brackets. This should solve your issue and allow PHPUnit to see the submit button.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what the exact cause of your problem is but it could be a couple of things.
I would have commented but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Firstly, have you run your plain html trough a validator? If it gives you any syntax errors try to fix them and run the unit test again. (You can try this one https://validator.w3.org/, just copy and paste your html)

Another cause may be that you have some javascript that modifies your DOM and Laravel testing can't handle that.

And lastly, you can try to set the 'value' attribute of your `<button>` to "Create"

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Create">Create</button>
```

Or change the `<button>` to an `<input>` with `type` attribute `"submit"` and `value` to `"Create"`

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" name="submit" value="Create" />
```

Answer (score 5):

From experience, unreachable field errors are normally caused by the buttons being outside of the `<form>` element, i've got a similair scenario where another section of the page is passed to the controller via `$request` but because it's not within the same immediate form element as everything else, PHPUnit can't assosciate it with the form.

It could be worth changing the method from `press()` to `click()` which just looks for something it can click on in general rather than attempting to match a submit button to the form.

As mentioned above as well, PHPUnit can't test JavaScript by itself (if you're using Javascript of course), you need something like Selenium to do that.

Without the markup it's quite hard to say, could you post the markup of your form?

Comment: That's the case. I had two forms: standard and an ajax form. Was not able to test the ajax form, but that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> The previous suggestions do not cover the business need of having the two submit buttons with same value.

**What we need to do is, override the default Laravel [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression.**

Instead of finding the first instance of the second submit button with the text, we'll tell Laravel to find the element with specific XPath of ours (the second submit button).

```
    $this->visit(route('user.login'));

    // replace `login-btn-2` with the id of your second button
    $button = $this->crawler->filterXPath('//*[@id="login-btn-2"]'); 

    $form = $button->form($inputs = ['email' => $user->email, 'password' => $password,]);

    $this->makeRequestUsingForm($form);

    $this->see(route('user.loggedin.dashboard'));
```

**Extra credit** If you're new to XPath, you can right click on the inspected source code on Chrome browser. The option you want is `Copy` > `Copy as XPath`

Answer (score 0):

You might find it works with the `submitForm` method:

```
$this->submitForm('Create', ['username' => 'john']);
```

Answer (score -1):

The main reason for this is when you have the submit button that looks like this. `<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>`. When you change the text of the button to other text other than Submit it would work fine. e.g `<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>`.